# Bash: List all modified files and concatenate

Tags: linux, bash

I want to list all the *.txt files modified over the last 7 days and concatenate in a single new.txt

Tried:

```
cat $(find *.txt -mtime -7 -ls) > new.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about your command ?

Comment: In the current directory only or in the subdirectories, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -mtime -8 -exec cat {} + > new.txt
```

From `man find`, maybe relevant:

> `-daystart`
>   Measure  times (for -amin, -atime, -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hours ago.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!

Comment: Might want to add `-type f` to the `find` command to restrict operation to regular files only.